# Repeat a user control as user clicks next?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a user control that consists of some textboxes and checkboxes. Once the user is finished filling the first one, they should be able to add one more form by clicking an "add another record" link button.

How can I repeat this usercontrol as the user clicks?

I am supposed to use C# only.

Comment: Why not to reuse the same control? Plrease provide some architectural details.

Comment: Do you want to create new user control on the fly when user finished entering?

Comment: Yes, I want to create link first when user click on it, it should show the form to fill out and it automatically add one more link in the bottom which enables to fill one more form for user.

Answer (score 0):

So, we are talking of UserControl where your fields are located (I mean, that this is a one class inherited from UserControl or Control. )

There are a lot of ways to do it. But, I think, to be mode 'code concise' is to use FlowLayoutPanel
a) Create this panel. (through visual designer i.e.)
b) When user clicks, create your control
c) add your control to layout panel.

```
 var myControl = new MyControlWithForm();
 flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(myControl);
```

One could use flowLayoutPanel1.Controls array to process all filled forms afterwards.

Comment: I think you are talking about windows forms, but I want to create in web application.

Comment: Then if you place only C# in the tags, please describe is it classic ASP.NET controls, MVC.NET, silverlight or something else, you are talking about.

Comment: It is in classic ASP.NET and c#